# document.getElementById("#").innerHTML = "Hello " + user + "!"; not working

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a javascript function as follows:

```
function userNameEntered() {
var user = document.forms["user"] ["name"].value;
document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Hello " + text + "!";
}
```

It accesses this `<form>`:

```
<form method="get" name="user" onsubmit="userNameEntered()">
<p>Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="username">
<input type="submit" onclick="userNameEntered()" value="Submit" id="usersubmit">
</form>
```

When I try it out I see the text implement for less then a second then disappear. Any ideas? I thought it might be because `user` is not in a global scope, so I tried declaring it before the function, and it didn't even show at all. I'm slightly confused as I can't see any possible problems.

Comment: Use `return false;` from the submit event handler

Comment: Also add `action="javascript:void(0);"` to your form tag.

Comment: @Andy This is a answer, not a comment.

Comment: Too short for an answer - a comment is fine.

Comment: First time I've been told off for _not_ writing an answer :)

Comment: @Andy I do, I just didn't include it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent default form action (which is submit with page reload) by returning `false` from onsubmit handler (`onsubmit="return userNameEntered()"`). You also need to `return false` from `userNameEntered` function.

Then, remember to remove redundant `onclick` handler (avoid using onclick for form submission) and add element with id="Name" somewhere.

```js
function userNameEntered() {
  var user = document.forms["user"]["name"].value;
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Hello " + user + "!";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" name="user" onsubmit="return userNameEntered()">
  <p>Name: <span id="Name"></span></p>
  <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="username">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="usersubmit">
</form>
```

Also note that you probably want `"Hello " + user + "!";` not `text`.

Comment: Form will still submit in Chrome without `action="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: @AaronGillion Thanks again! ... or you can `return false` from the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use return false in your function

```
    function userNameEntered() {
    var user = document.forms["user"] ["name"].value;
    document.getElementById("enter code hereName").innerHTML = "Hello " + text + "!";
    return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the form from being submitted, as the page is being reloaded are the post. This is why you are seeing it briefly, and then it "disappears".

To stop this, you need to stop the form being submitted:

```
function userNameEntered()  {
    var text = document.forms["user"]["name"].value;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Hello " + text + "!"; 
    return false;
}
```

You also have some errors: your form element is `name`, but you reference `Name`, you assign `var user` but use `text`.

Answer (score 0):

It's disappearing because the page is reloading after the form is submitted.

To stop this try:

```
function userNameEntered() {
  var user = document.forms["user"] ["name"].value;
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Hello " + text + "!";
  return false;
}
```

And:

```
<form method="get" name="user" onsubmit="return userNameEntered()">
  <p>Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="username">
  <input type="submit" onclick="userNameEntered()" value="Submit" id="usersubmit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent default form action is not occurred..due to this values may disappear

```
<form method="get" name="user" onsubmit="userNameEntered();return false;">
<p>Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="username">
<input type="submit" onclick="userNameEntered()" value="Submit" id="usersubmit">
</form>


        <script>
            function userNameEntered() {
                debugger;
                var user = document.forms["user"]["name"].value;
                document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Hello " + user + "!";
            }
        </script>
or

  $('#usersubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = document.forms["user"]["name"].value;
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Hello " + user + "!";
    });
```